# How to link same index elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.buttons,
.weChangeColor {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.weChangeColor p {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.toggleColor {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <p><a href="#">FirstLink</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">SecondLink</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">ThirdLink</a></p>
</div>

<div class="weChangeColor">
  <p>FirstPara</p>
  <p>SecondPara</p>
  <p>ThirdPara</p>
</div>
```

In the code above, What I want is that, when first `link` is clicked, first `p` should change background to green .

When second link is clicked, second `p` should change background to green, and so on.

Basically linking same elements of different classes having same index.

**I NEED THE JAVASCRIPT CODE REQUIRED TO ACHIEVE THIS.**

How can I achieve this result ?

Jquery is more than welcome.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @athimohan updated.

Comment: where are you applying the toggleColor class defined above?

Comment: @Kosch that's the code i need . The a and p tag having same array index shall be linked.

Comment: Can html be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the code might solve your issue

Thanks

```js
jQuery('.buttons p').click(function(){
  var ClickedElemenet = jQuery(this).index();
  var GetElement = jQuery('.weChangeColor p').get(ClickedElemenet);
  jQuery(GetElement).toggleClass('toggleColor');
});
```

```css
.buttons,
.weChangeColor {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.weChangeColor p {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.toggleColor {
  background: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <p><a href="#">FirstLink</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">SecondLink</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">ThirdLink</a></p>
</div>

<div class="weChangeColor">
  <p>FirstPara</p>
  <p>SecondPara</p>
  <p>ThirdPara</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Right answer and easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery `index()` and `eq()` functions.

Here is an example:

```js
$(".buttons p").click(function(){
   $(".weChangeColor p").eq($(this).index()).toggleClass("toggleColor");
   $(this).toggleClass("toggleColor");
});
```

```css
.buttons,
.weChangeColor {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.weChangeColor p {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
}

p.toggleColor {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <p><a href="#">FirstLink</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">SecondLink</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">ThirdLink</a></p>
</div>

<div class="weChangeColor">
  <p>FirstPara</p>
  <p>SecondPara</p>
  <p>ThirdPara</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome and accurate.

Answer (score 2):

For pure CSS solution you can use pseudo class `:target` and target `p` by giving `id` to each `p`

Like this:

```css
.buttons,
.weChangeColor {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

:target {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <p><a href="#p1">FirstLink</a></p>
  <p><a href="#p2">SecondLink</a></p>
  <p><a href="#p3">ThirdLink</a></p>
</div>

<div class="weChangeColor">
  <p id="p1">FirstPara</p>
  <p id="p2">SecondPara</p>
  <p id="p3">ThirdPara</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is perfectly right but just doesn't fit my scenario . Other than that its correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make it in js with jQuery like this :

```js
jQuery('.buttons p').click(function(){
  jQuery('.weChangeColor p').eq($(this).index()).toggleClass('toggleColor');
});
```

```css
.buttons,
.weChangeColor {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.weChangeColor p {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.weChangeColor p.toggleColor {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <p><a href="#">FirstLink</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">SecondLink</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">ThirdLink</a></p>
</div>

<div class="weChangeColor">
  <p>FirstPara</p>
  <p>SecondPara</p>
  <p>ThirdPara</p>
</div>
```

Or make it with class or id or data

Comment: @YashYadav you can check now